# My bagel recipe calls for 1 tbsp of barley malt syrup. I have diastatic malt powder. How much powder would equal the tbsp of syrup?

Tags: substitutions, bagels

My bagel recipe calls for 1 tbsp barley malt syrup. I have diastatic malt powder. How much powder would equal the tbsp of syrup?